# haskell words from alphabet of a given length

Tags: haskell

I have this function that generates a list of all words with a min length 0 and max length n, equals given as an input to the function:

```
import Data.List

words :: Int -> String -> [String]
words 0 alph = [[]]
words n alph = words (n-1) alph ++ [ ch:w | w <-words (n-1) alph, ch <- alph]
```

When I run this, the output is following:

```
> words 3 "AB"
["","A","B","A","B","AA","BA","AB","BB","A","B","AA","BA","AB","BB","AA","BA","AB","BB","AAA","BAA","ABA","BBA","AAB","BAB","ABB","BBB"]
```

The problem here is, that there are some words repeating, in this example, especially the words of length of 2 ("AA" is 3 times there). Can you see what am I doing wrong in my function, or do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `words (n-1) alph` in the list comprehension will not only contain words of length `n-1` but also with a smaller length, because how you defined `words`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `words (n-1) alph` in the list comprehension does not only yield words of length `n-1` but also `n-2`, `n-3`, etc., since that is how you defined the `words` function.

It might be better to make a helper function that only generates words of length *n* and then use that in an extra function that constructs strings with lengths up to *n*:

```
words :: Int -> String -> [String]
words 0 alph = [[]]
words n alph = [ ch:w | w <-words (n-1) alph, ch <- alph]

wordsUpTo :: Int -> String -> [String]
wordsUpTo n alph = concatMap (flip words alph) [0 .. n]
```

However `words` already exists, this is just a special case of [**`replicateM :: Applicative m = > Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), so we can write this as:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

wordsUpTo :: Int -> String -> [String]
wordsUpTo n alph = [0 .. n] >>= (`replicateM` alph)
```

which will produce:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> wordsUpTo 3 "AB"
["","A","B","AA","AB","BA","BB","AAA","AAB","ABA","ABB","BAA","BAB","BBA","BBB"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Applicative` instance for lists effectively computes a cross-product,

```
> (,) <$> ["A", "B"] <*> ["C", "D"]
[("A","C"),("A","D"),("B","C"),("B","D")]
```

elements of which can be joined with `(++)` instead of `(,)`:

```
> (++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*> ["C", "D"]
["AC","AD","BC","BD"]
```

If you repeatedly apply this operation, you'll get the strings you want:

```
> (++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*> [""] -- base case
["A","B"]
> (++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*> ["A","B"]
["AA","AB","BA","BB"]
> (++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*> ["AA","AB","BA","BB"]
["AAA","AAB","ABA","ABB","BAA","BAB","BBA","BBB"]
```

The function you want to repeat is the section `((++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*>)`, which from now on we'll refer to as `f`:

```
> f = ((++) <$> ["A", "B"] <*>)
```

This repeated application is captured by the `iterate` function, which repeatedly feeds the output of one function application as the input of the next.

```
> take 3 $ iterate f [""]
[[""],["A","B"],["AA","AB","BA","BB"]]
```

We'll want to concatenate the results into a single list:

```
> take 7 $ concat $ iterate f [""]
["","A","B","AA","AB","BA","BB"]
```

So *all* combinations is just

```
allWords alph = concat $ iterate f [""]
  where f = ((++) <$> alph <*>)
```

To get the elements with some maximum length, we can either

1. Use `takeWhile (\x -> length x <= n)`, or
2. Use `take (2^(n+1) - 1)` (given the order in which items are generated, all the strings of a given length occur before longer strings, and we can compute the total number of strings with a given maximum length)

So we can define either

```
words n = takeWhile p . allWords
  where p x = length x < 4
```

or

```
words n = take n' . allWords
```